# Error message: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, for-loop, indexoutofboundsexception

I got error message:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

With this code:

```
public class probno {

    public static void main(String arghs[]) {

        int niz[]={3,2,5,6,8};
        promjena(niz);

        for(int y:niz){
            System.out.println(y);
        }
    }   

    public static void promjena (int x[]){

        for (int brojac=0;brojac<=x.length;brojac++){
            x[brojac]+=5;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should use < instead of <=

```
for (int brojac=0;brojac<=x.length;brojac++){
    x[brojac]+=5;
}
```

If you have array which consists say of one element, its length will be 1, but the index of it's only element will be 0
If you try to access an element with index 1 (i.e. array.length) you will get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
for (int brojac=0;brojac<=x.length;brojac++)
```

to

```
for (int brojac=0;brojac<x.length;brojac++)
```

Array indices start in 0 and end in length-1.